# How long does it take the build the Ewok village

Tags: lego-group

How long does it take to build the Ewok village

Comment: That's kind of impossible to answer beyond "Depends on your skill level".

Answer (score 4):

Build speed depends very much on your ability as a builder to understand instructions, organize the pieces in advance, and pick & place those pieces in the right position in your build. Additionally, the complexity of the set (simple versus complex building techniques, e.g. SNOT (Studs Not On Top) techniques are considered complex) might make a similar sized set more difficult. The complexity is often determined through the Age range specified on the box. So there is no exact answer here.

But as an indication, the set [10236 LEGO Ewok Village](http://shop.lego.com/en-US/Ewok-Village-10236) contains 1990 pieces and is rated 12+. That age range makes it a moderately difficult build (There is 14+ and 16+ for more complex builds).

First you need to take time to part out the set, put like elements together (LEGO suggests sorting by color, you could also sort by type of piece which will make your job slightly easier - put 1x1 bricks together, leaf pieces together, 1x4 plates together etc.). Opening the box gently by slicing a sharp knife through the seals on the flap (so you don't damage the box), emptying and opening the bags and dumping it all on your work surface takes 1 minute. To pick a piece and sort it, I am assuming takes you 1 second - since there are 1990 pieces this means the sorting activity alone will take you a good 30 minutes (33 to be precise).

Now it is time for the build. Assuming that you can put a piece into your build in about 10 seconds (includes find time, reviewing the instructions, sometimes flipping the page, and averages out for easier and more difficult building steps), with 1990 pieces this means you will spend 332 minutes on your build, or roughly 5hrs and 30 minutes, excluding any breaks.

**Putting it all together, assuming my estimates and assumptions are correct, your total build time should be between 6 and 6.5 hours.**

Good luck and have fun, because that Ewok Village set looks pretty awesome!

Comment: Oops - made a conversion mistake there - should have been 5hrs 30mins, so total build is somewhere between 6 and 6.5 hours assuming my assumptions are correct

Comment: I thought in large modern LEGO sets you would have numbered bags that should be opened when needed, not all at once.

Comment: Sure, but the calculation is much more difficult if you have to take bags and pieces per bag into account. So I simplified to get to a workable answer. Approximation should still be valid even when working to smaller subsets of the entire set.